# React tag name with a capital letter

Tags: reactjs

I had a stoopid idea that using react it would be quite convenient to generate xml. But it's case-sensitive. So I have a problem to create tags with a custom name to the template.
Render the `<some></some>` tag is obtained. But the `<Some></Some>` tag is perceived by the react as a component and says that it can't find such a thing.
Is it possible to render a tag with a capital letter in the name via react?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by `tags`? Do you mean custom react components that you are rendering in other react components? React components need to be capitalized: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type . Or do you mean non react [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) that you are trying to render inside of react components?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `html` tags are case insensitive. That means that `<p>` means the same as `<P>`. Therefore I don't see any reason to render a capitalized custom tag with react.

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky just the opposite. When I say tag it meant that I want to have a <Some></Some> tag in html in browser.

Comment: `Some` that is not a react component? How is `Some` defined? Is it an HTML custom element? Please share related code.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky But `<Some>` in html is the same as `<some>`, as tags in html are case insensitive. So you can just stick with `<some>`. Also `<sOmE>` would be the same.

Comment: @trixn I had a stoopid idea that using react it would be quite convenient to generate xml. And it's case-sensitive.

Comment: @muturgan That is something that is worth mentioning in your question, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @trixn i dont think so. can't you just believe me that I REALLY need this?

Comment: @trixn well, looks like you are right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "HTML" you write in React is not HTML, its JSX. In JSX, custom components have to be capitalized, hence, you can't use regular HTML elements with a capital letter in JSX.

You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).